# SQL Query -IF EXISTS and WITH

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, exists

Hi have a stored procedure with WITH keyword that returns a resultset as follows

```
WITH p as(...),
mp as (select *, x.name from p left join x on ...)
```

Now i want to say

```
IF EXISTS (select * from mp where pid is not null and id != pid)
THEN 
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM cp left join mp on ...

  END 
ELSE
BEGIN  SELECT * FROM mp where...
END
```

Here i am facing some syntax error this select should be returned back from stored procedure

**UPDATE**

I have put it as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (

    --get all parent records that matches RIDE ID
    SELECT * FROM mp WHERE pid is null or pid = id
    UNION --get parent of a child that matches RIDE ID
        SELECT pl.* [i have specified exact same columns in this select]
        FROM pl 
            left join mp on pl.plc_id = mp.PrimaryPlacementId  
            left join reg on reg.usr_id = mp.plc_usr and isnull(reg.usr_isdeleted, 0) = 0 --and reg.usr_active = 1
            left join ut on ut.cut_id = mp.plc_unit
            left join f on f.fac_id = mp.plc_facility and isnull(f.fac_isdeleted, 0) = 0
            left join s on s.sem_id = mp.plc_semester and isnull(s.sem_isdeleted, 0) = 0
        WHERE mp.pid != id AND mp.pid is not null

) x
```

This one seems to work ok - basically pid contains the parent id

My mp=pl table has the following structure

### id | name | pid

1  | sam  | 1

2  | sid  | 1

so basically first is the parent record and second is the child record.

so what i want is - if i search 'sam' then record 1 is returned
and if i search 'sid' again record one is returned

i.e if u search by parent id or child id the parent record should be returned or those whose pid is null

Comment: You can't.  A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  You cannot return the columns just from `mp` sometimes and at other times from both `mp` and `cp`.

Comment: Unless your result set has exactly the same column names and types in both cases... you may use a `UNION` in that case. Maybe if you give more details we can propose a solution.

Comment: yes i will have exact same column names * is put to decrease complexity from original query

Comment: i am pasting my solution above please comment if it can be improved or is buggy